# How to get Python.Net to use Python 3.6 Anaconda Distribution

Tags: python, python.net

How do I get Python.NET to use Python 3.6? I copied the sample code below and when I run it I get the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'python35': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
   at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize()
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable`1 args, Boolean setSysArgv)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv)
   at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize()
   at Python.Runtime.Py.GIL()
```

I don't have Python 3.5 and thus no python35.dll. I have Python 3.6. It's part of the Anaconda Distribution. How do I get Python.Net to use that?

The sample code:

```
    using (Py.GIL())
    {
        dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
        Console.WriteLine(np.cos(np.pi * 2));

        dynamic sin = np.sin;
        Console.WriteLine(sin(5));

        double c = np.cos(5) + sin(5);
        Console.WriteLine(c);

        dynamic a = np.array(new List<float> { 1, 2, 3 });
        Console.WriteLine(a.dtype);

        dynamic b = np.array(new List<float> { 6, 5, 4 }, dtype: np.int32);
        Console.WriteLine(b.dtype);

        Console.WriteLine(a * b);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Update to answer questions in the comments:
I installed Python.net by getting the NuGet package "pythonnet_py35_dotnet" It's version is v2.3.0.

python -c "import sys; print (sys.version)" gives

```
3.6.0 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

"where python" gives

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\python.exe
```

Comment: how did you install pythonnet? which version? can you show output of `where python`? also show output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"`? finally have a look at installation and troubleshooting instructions in pythonnet wiki: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/wiki

Comment: I updated the question to include answers to @denfromufa questions.

Comment: Your version from nuget is clearly for Python 3.5 as you can see from the name. So for Python 3.6 please use other installation channels from wiki.

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes it easy to miss the obvious. I installed it using Conda and it's working fine

Answer (score 5):

The working solution for me is:

*Consider I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express,

1. Add a reference to `Python.Runtime.dll` in References in Solution Explorer(if you have trouble finding the DLL file easily, just try using [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) app on windows)
2. Add the following line at the top of your C# code.

   ```
   using Python.Runtime;
   ```
3. Add the following code before calling `using (Py.GIL()){...}`

   ```
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", @"path-to-the-directory-containing-python-interpreter.exe", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
   Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONHOME", @"path-to-the-directory-containing-python-interpreter.exe", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
   ```
4. Finally, the **most important thing** is to set your system architecture type in the Build tab of the Properties in Solution Explorer.

In my case(not using virtual environments), it's like the following pictures:

[image: Steps 1 to 3.]

[image: Step 4.]

Hope it works!